# How to use fread correctly?

Tags: c, fread

I've seen two ways of providing the size of a file to `fread`.

If lets say I have a char array `data`, a `file` pointer and `filesize` is the size of the file in bytes then the first is:

```
fread(data, 1, filesize, file);
```

And the second:

```
fread(data, filesize, 1, file);
```

My question is, is there any difference between the two lines of code?
and which line of code is more "correct".

Also, I'm assuming the `1` in the two lines of code actually means `sizeof(char)`, is that correct?

Comment: Learn to look up the proper manual of the libraries you're using. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) for the complete detail on `fread`.

Comment: I did look at the manual, specifically here [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread). But I was still uncertain because I saw both ways in working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Argument 2**: size of each member
>
> **Argument 3**: Number of objects you want to read

Now your question:

> is there any difference between the two lines of code?

```
fread(data, 1, filesize, file);
```

Reads `filesize` objects pointed by data where size of each object is 1 byte. **If less than `filesize` bytes are read, those would be read partially.**

```
fread(data, filesize, 1, file);
```

Reads `1` object pointed by data where size of this object is `filesize` bytes. If less than `filesize` bytes are available, none would be read.

Do whatever is the requirement of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The first tells fread to read elements of size 1, filesize of them.

The second tells fread to read filesize elements of size of 1.

In theory both produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In practice and theory both produce the same result. But if you respect the 'fread' standard, the first line is the correct one.